# How to install Apache Atlas 1.1.0 on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: apache, maven, installation, apache-atlas

I am trying to setup Apache Atlas on my system. I am encountering the following error

I read the article as suggested (http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException) but I was unable to understand what it was trying to convey.

```
[INFO] >>> findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.1:check (findbugs-check) > :findbugs @ apache-atlas >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.1:findbugs (findbugs) @ apache-atlas ---
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 (file:/Users/r0r017e/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.0/groovy-all-2.4.0.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
...
[INFO] Apache Atlas Server Build Tools 1.0 ................ SUCCESS [  0.632 s]
[INFO] apache-atlas 1.1.0 ................................. FAILURE [  3.341 s]
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.1:findbugs (findbugs) on project apache-atlas: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.1:findbugs for parameter pluginArtifacts: Cannot assign configuration entry 'pluginArtifacts' with value '${plugin.artifacts}' of type java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to property of type java.util.ArrayList -> [Help 1]
```

I need to setup Apache Atlas via Cassandra as a backend store. I am new to data governance and open source solutions, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just testing Atlas I suggest using a docker image. The following worked for me. https://github.com/michalmiklas/atlas-docker

Comment: can you share more how you make it work? With MacOS Majave, I run into errors after atlas server started. in the end, the Atlas server shutdown.